# How do I show an already hidden field of a custom content type to a specific authenticated user?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a custom content type whose fields are *Name*, *Description*, and *URL* which is hidden by default. I want to show the latter field to the authenticated users who have flagged the node containing it. (I installed the *Flag* module for the flags.)
The flagging and displaying the flagged items are working fine. The only thing I am having trouble with is the hidden URL.

Can anyone guide me on how I can do this?

I looked into using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) modules, but I don't think they would help and they seem to be an overkill for this particular task. I also looked into implementing `hook_page_alter()`, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to hide/show an entity field when an entity is rendered, but a hidden field is automatically removed from the base class used to implement an entity view, the [`EntityDisplayBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityDisplayBase.php/class/EntityDisplayBase/8.9.x) class. Its constructor calls [`EntityDisplayBase::init()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityDisplayBase.php/function/EntityDisplayBase%3A%3Ainit/8.9.x), which contains the following code.

```php
// @todo Remove handling of 'type' in https://www.drupal.org/node/2799641.
if (!isset($options['region']) && !empty($options['type']) && $options['type'] === 'hidden') {
  $options['region'] = 'hidden';
  @trigger_error("Support for using 'type' => 'hidden' in a component is deprecated in drupal:8.3.0 and is removed from drupal:9.0.0. Use 'region' => 'hidden' instead. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2801513", E_USER_DEPRECATED);
}
if (!empty($options['region']) && $options['region'] === 'hidden') {
  $this
    ->removeComponent($name);
}
```

Since that code is executed when the entity display class is build, every hook running before the entity is rendered would not get those hidden components (which are entity fields and extra fields).

Rather than setting an entity field as hidden by default, and then show it when some conditions are met (which would not be possible), you can set the field as visible by default, and hide it when some conditions are met. Which hook to use depends also from when that field needs to be hidden.

If the entity field needs to be hidden only when specific view modes (a.k.a. entity display modes) are used, then [`hook_entity_view_display_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_display_alter/8.9.x) can be implemented.

```php
use \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;

function mymodule_entity_view_display_alter(EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, array $context) {
  // Leave field labels out of the search index.
  if ($context['entity_type'] == 'node' && $context['view_mode'] == 'the view module you are interested to') {
    $components = $display->getComponents();
    $name = 'The machine name of the field you want to hide.'
    if (isset($components[$name])) {
      $options = $components[$name];
      // Verify the conditions to hide the field are met.
      $options['region'] = 'hidden';
      $display->setComponent($name, $options);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code I shown assumes you are using at least Drupal 8.3; otherwise, it needs to be changed. (Instead of `$options['region']`, it needs set `$options['type'] to` 'hidden'`.)

If you need to hide the field independently from the view mode used to render the node, then the hook to implement is [`hook_entity_field_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_field_access/8.9.x).

```php
use \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
use \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

function mymodule_entity_field_access($operation, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, AccountInterface $account, FieldItemListInterface $items = NULL) {
  if ($field_definition->getName() == 'the field you are interested to' && $operation == 'view') {
    // Verify the conditions to hide the field are met.
    // Return AccessResult::forbidden() if the conditions are met.
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
  // Otherwise, return AccessResult::neutral(), which lets Drupal core
  // or third-party modules decide.
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

I used `AccessResult::forbidden()` just as example. You could also verify the account passed to the hook has a specific permission with `AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'permission to check')`, or verify the account has one or more permissions with `AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermissions($account, ['list', 'of', 'permissions'], 'OR')`.

Keep in mind that, implementing `hook_entity_field_access()`, you would also avoid the field is indexed by the Search module. If you want the field to be indexed by the Search module, you need to implement `hook_entity_view_display_alter()` and leave the field visible when `$context['view_mode']` is equal to `'search_index'`.

As alternative, you could create a view mode that is similar to the view mode used to show the node, but where the hidden field is visible. Implementing [`hook_entity_view_mode_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_mode_alter/8.9.x) you can alter the view mode to use the one you created.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

function mymodule_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, EntityInterface $entity, $context) {
  // For nodes, change the view mode when it is teaser.
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node' && ($view_mode == 'full' || $view_mode == 'teaser')) {
    // Verify the conditions are met.
    $view_mode = 'my_custom_view_mode';
  }
}
```

Comment: first of all thank you for such a detailed response. 
Secondly, I am onboard setting the URL field as not hidden by default and hide it on all the pages and views.
I am using drupal 7, so I can't use the above code. 
Also, can you please guide me further on where should I implement these hooks? Like, If my module is named _Picture_, I would have to implement the hook in the picture.module file? I tried implementing the _node_view_alter_ in my picture.module file but it didn't got called on any page.

Comment: This is an answer for Drupal 8; I am going to post an answer for Drupal 7 too.

Answer (score 0):

With Drupal 7, I would still set the field to be visible by default and hide it when some conditions are met, but differently from Drupal 8, I would implement [`hook_node_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7.x). (In the following code, replace *field_of_interest* with the machine name of the field you need to hide.)

```php
function mymodule_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  if ($build['#view_mode'] == 'full' && isset($build['field_of_interest'])) {
    // Make the field not accessible to the current user, if you need to
    // hide it to the current user.
    $build['field_of_interest']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

The code checks the view mode to avoid altering the view mode Drupal core or third-party modules use in particular occasions, for example *search_index* which is used when a node is indexed by the Search module, *feed* which is used when a node is rendered for RSS feed, or *print* which is used from the Book module when the content of a book is exported as HTML.

Alternatively, as with Drupal 8, it's still possible to avoid the currently logged-in user has access to the field when viewing the node containing it. In this case, the field would be hidden independently from the view mode used to render the node. The hook to implement is [`hook_field_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7.x).

```php
function mymodule_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
  if ($field['field_name'] == 'field_of_interest' && $op == 'view') {
    // Check the conditions are met, and return FALSE when the field must be hidden.
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Alternatively, you could set a custom view mode where the field is hidden by default, and tell Drupal to use your custom view mode when some conditions you check are met. The hook to implement in this case is [`hook_entity_view_mode_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_mode_alter/7.x).

```php
function mymodule_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, $context) {
  if ($context['entity_type'] == 'node' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    // Check the conditions are met and set the view mode to the custom one.
    $view_mode = 'my_custom_view_mode';
  }
}
```